# iPhone language setting and localization to Norsk (bokmal)

Tags: iphone, localization

i have a real weird thing going on. I am trying to get the language settings in my

> *strings file for "Norwegian Bokmal - Norway"

to display. But It will not work and always takes the default.

I set the

> iPhone language to Norsk (bokmal)

and have the file setup correctly.

This app has already 8 language *string files and Norwegian is the 9th.

Did anybody experience something similar?

I tried 2 different iPhones (both iOS5) and the simulator (iOS4.3) - there is no way my app recognizes the Norwegian strings file - it always shows up with the default language.
Thanks very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you use the correct language code in your folder structure? I believe it should be "nb".

Comment: thanks for that hint - I just checked, there is a folder nb-NO and I created an extra nb folder - still it takes the default language...

Comment: I wonder if there is confusion on the language code, there are 3 different ones for Norwegian. You could also try "no", it's the code for Norwegian (and even "nn" for Norwegian Nynorsk but that would be very weird)

Comment: Now I tried everything: Norwegian Nynorsk, Norwegian Nynorsk - Norway, Norwegian Bokmal - Norway, but none is taken when setting iPhone to Norsk Bokmal. I guess I have to contact Apple directly then...

Comment: Sorry about that. I tried on my machine and "nb" seems to be the correct language code. And this Apple doc [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/LanguageDesignations.html) says that on iOS "only the language designator is considered" and " if your project includes language-specific project directories with both a language and region designator, those directories are ignored". So it should be nb rather than nb-NO. As you tried this, something else must be going on.

Comment: I found the problem thanks to your hint about the folder name. When I added the localization for Norwegian in my project it always created nb-NO while in a new test project it created nb correctly and it worked. So instead of adding a localization with the little + in the Localiation window of the file I manually created a nb folder and put the file there - then I dreagged this file into my project and voila it took this file in the nb folder - now it's OK Thanks very much!